# Line2D thickness (too thick)

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, awt, java-2d

I have to draw a diagram. And I use the AWT Library to do that.

The problem is, that I need to draw really thin lines. 
But I always get lines that are too thick.

Here you can see, what I mean.

[image]

Here is the code that draw these lines

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(300, 60, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics g = image.createGraphics();
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.001f,BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER));
Shape s = new Line2D.Double(new Point2D.Double(x_pos, unten - 9),
                            new Point2D.Double(x_pos, unten - 4));
g2.draw(s);
```

Comment: Very nice question. I am interested in a elegant solution for this as well.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
Shape s = new Line2D.Double(new Point2D.Double(x_pos, unten - 9),
                            new Point2D.Double(x_pos, unten - 4));
g2.draw(s);
```

try using

```
g2.drawLine(x_pos, unten - 9, x_pos, unten - 4);
```

The `Shape` stuff is not really able to cope with thicknesses lower than 1... (as far as I know)

And please don't mix different languages while coding, this gives me eye cancer (even if it is german) :P. Best is, to just stick with english variable names as all the keyword are english too.

Comment: Sorry for the german words. The reason why we are using them is that we have to port legacy code from vb to java, and we have to use the same variable names. Yes I already used the drawLine Method, but I get the same result with it. My first solution was to set up a scale for it. That works fine but than I would not be able to add some digits above the diagramm. The second reason why I am using Shape for drawing is, that I nead double or float values for drawing!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.5f));
```

or any other value that suits your needs.